# Why "0 not equivalent to "_1 when arguments are one dimensional arrays?

Tags: j

Why these two expression not equivalent in this situation?

```
   0 1 2 ,"(0)/ 0 1
0 0
0 1

1 0
1 1

2 0
2 1

   0 1 2 ,"(_1)/ 0 1
|length error
|   0 1 2    ,"(_1)/0 1
```

Actually what I'm trying to do...

```
a =: 0 1 2 3 4 5 ; 0 1 2 ; 0 1
```

Want to get all possible combinations

```
,"0/&>/ a
```

This code doesn't work 
This works though:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 ,"(0 1)/ 0 1 2 ,"(0 0)/ 0 1
```

But, of course, I want to write in short form

```
,"0/&>/ a
```

The problem is that all terms should be

```
,"(0 1)/
```

but last

```
,"(0 0)/
```

Comment: I found another amazing approach of getting this result already: 6 3 2 #: i.6*3*2 But I want to understand how to do using comma-slash as well.

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Are you opposed to `{ a` or `> , { a`?

Comment: I'm learning J by solving Project Euler. Stunning language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help, as what it doing is simply appending at a rank of 0

```
    0  ,"(0)/ 0 1
0 0
0 1
      1  ,"(0)/ 0 1
1 0
1 1
      2  ,"(0)/ 0 1
2 0
2 1
```

For the actual solution to the problem you are investigating, have you looked at Catalogue? `{`

```
   {a
┌─────┬─────┐
│0 0 0│0 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│0 1 0│0 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│0 2 0│0 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│1 0 0│1 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│1 1 0│1 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│1 2 0│1 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│2 0 0│2 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│2 1 0│2 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│2 2 0│2 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│3 0 0│3 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│3 1 0│3 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│3 2 0│3 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│4 0 0│4 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│4 1 0│4 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│4 2 0│4 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘

┌─────┬─────┐
│5 0 0│5 0 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│5 1 0│5 1 1│
├─────┼─────┤
│5 2 0│5 2 1│
└─────┴─────┘
```

Catalogue matches the Append Table:

```
  (>{a)-: 0 1 2 3 4 5 ,"(0 1)/ 0 1 2 ,"(0 0)/ 0 1
1
```

Comment: I was thinking about pointing out the `, b. 0`, `,"0 b. 0`, and `,"_1 b. 0`. Want to include those in your answer?

Comment: Oh, yes. Catalogue definitely is a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`"_1` is equivalent to `"0"_`

In other words, "_1 forms a verb which looks at all the data to find its rank and then derives another verb to work at one rank lower than that.